# How to configure NLog with Elmah in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, nlog, elmah

There is a NLog.Elmah library in the .NET Core version or there is another way to log information in Elmah from a .NET Core application?

Answer (score 0):

Neither ELMAH or NLog.Elmah works with .NET Core. NLog on itself works in .NET Core, of course, but not with ELMAH as a target. You have a couple of different options. You can use NLog with another target available for .NET Core. If you HAVE to use ELMAH, you might want to check out [ElmahCore](https://github.com/ElmahCore/ElmahCore). It's a port of ELMAH but for ASP.NET Core. I'm not sure if it works in something like a .NET Core console app. But if your project type is ASP.NET Core, it works with a SQL Database or a few other targets. There's also [elmah.io](https://elmah.io), which is a commercial cloud-logging platform. elmah.io supports both ELMAH, NLog and .NET Core.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my conjecture.